# how to stop auto save when record on data is edited

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have this form that has a subform containing records from table.
I want is when user clicked on the checkbox message will pop out "Do you want to approve application?" then when user clicks OK the value of the checkbox and other records edited will be saved in the table.
but I'm encountering when user edit a record it automatically updates the table.

here's sample of my [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBDRb.png):
here's my code:

```
Private Sub chkApproved_Click()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM RECORD WHERE ID = '" & Me.txtID & "' AND DATE = #" & Me.txtDate & "# "
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If Me.chkApproved = -1 Then
If MsgBox("Do you want to approve application?", vbOKCancel, "Leave Approval") = vbOK Then

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        rs.Edit
        rs.Fields("APPROVED_FLG") = Me.chkApproved.Value
        rs.Fields("LEAVE_FLG") = Me.chkLeave.Value
        rs.Fields("REMARKS") = Me.REMARKS
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.Requery
Else
    Me.chkApproved = 0
End If
Else
Exit Sub
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

And also I want to disable the leave checkbox when the approved checkbox is already checked. I tried to add it in my code but always ends up disabling all the checkbox.

I'm only new to this so I don't know that much.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access saves your changes immediately as a default behaviour because it's directly editing the database. I see you already have the Yes/No message box set up. Try running [Undo and Cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662181/is-there-a-way-to-override-automatic-record-updating-of-access-2007-forms-create) if the user declines the change.

To disable a single unbound object in a continuous form, try [this link](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/6692/Overcoming-unbound-continuous-forms-limitations-by-staging-data.html).

Comment: I tried that code but it ends up disabling all the checkbox under paid_leave. Only the line which the approved flg is checked, the paid_leave checkbox on that line should be disabled.  thanks for your advice.

Comment: @geekypanda Are you using a form with multiple checkboxes and one paid_leave checkbox, or a continuous form with multiple paid_leave checkboxes, one per record? The code in my answer will work if there is one paid_leave checkbox on the form.

Comment: im using continuous form with multiple paid_leave checkboxes, one per record.

Comment: @geekypanda How about [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/6692/Overcoming-unbound-continuous-forms-limitations-by-staging-data.html) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267315/dynamic-text-box-content-on-an-access-continuous-form)?

Comment: thanks for the help i followed the first link and it worked. thank you!

Comment: @geekypanda You're welcome! I edited the link into my answer.